# Why was an answer to the maven-jlink plugin which tells that a fork of the project can do what was wanted deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, specific-answer, self-promotion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow answer: [Is there a way to add maven dependencies while using the maven-jlink-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103221/is-there-a-way-to-add-maven-dependencies-while-using-the-maven-jlink-plugin/54493172#54493172)

Why was my answer to the maven-jlink plugin which tells that an open-source fork of the project can do what was wanted while the original maven-jlink-plugin can not do that deleted?

IMHO this tells exactly how the problem in the question can be solved and it also already got a vote for that before it was deleted.

I also posted the same reply on another post with a question in the same problem space but that was also deleted.

It is currently a common problem which lots of developers have on how to create custom Java Runtime Images which contain external dependencies to 3rd-party libraries which are not real Java modules but automatic modules or non-modular jar files.

I have developed a solution to this problem which is an open-source project on GitHub.

I really see no reason why I should not mention this project in a Stack Overflow answer so that other developers can use this project participate in it or maybe fork it and modify it to solve their problem.

Comment: `I also posted the same reply on another post with a question in the same problem space but that was also deleted` --> you aren't allowed to post the same answer, this is what have triggered  the moderator intention thus the deletion

Comment: ^ and the moderator already gave you the reason within the comment section : *Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. And be very careful about posting answers that consist of little more than a recommendation to use a tool that you built. Please read the help center before posting.* (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493264/8620333)

Comment: Relevant Uber Meta FAQ post: [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227).

Comment: These answers were not only flagged automatically by the system as being duplicates, but they were also flagged by community members for being essentially spam. The comment I left underneath one of them should have been sufficient to explain the rationale behind deletion. I also endorse Robert Longson's answer below. Search Meta to find more advice on how to constructively suggest tools that you have built or are affiliated with; we've had this discussion many times in the past.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is not specific to the question, it's just a copy and paste from the usage page of the plugin. As such it's purpose is mainly self promotion which is disallowed here.

Comment: Ok understood thank you. Although I may have a slightly different opinion about the being specific to the question part.

Comment: Actuall what happend is not that the answer was a copy and paste of the usage page.

Comment: I had just almost the same problem as the poster on Stackoverflow ... I created my own solution to solve the problem and than I saw the question here. That gave me a reason to update the usage page and I did that at the same time while answering the question. I am new to posting here and I apologize for the "self-promotion" that might have slipped me .... But this is just how I solved a similar problem than the poster and I thought that might be helpful.

Comment: However to make use of your answer we'd need to visit your site. Given that you have solved the problem an acceptable answer would be.... Here's how you solve the problem... <enter complete solution here without having to use your tools/site>. Oh and by the way I've also put this code somewhere else where you can use it as a package if you wish to do so. That way the answer is complete and standalone, no visits to any external site are required, although if the reader so wishes they can visit your site, they don't have to in order to get a solution.

Comment: Here's some [further reading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) should you wish to find out more about what is required for a good answer.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: Ok I just posted a new answer explaining the technical background instead of explaining my concrete solution. Thanks for teaching me on how to improve my answers - there is a reason for why things like these have moderators.